# Laravel Excel - Data side by side in blocks

Tags: php, laravel, csv, laravel-excel

I'm trying to create an export out of my data in laravel. For this I use the package laravel-excel. Therefore I have to interate over all machinery and writing the blocks with the data next to each other like so:

[image]

```php
    public function collection()
    {
        return Metric::whereDate('created_at','>=',$this->startDate->toDateTimeString())
            ->whereDate('created_at','<=',$this->endDate->toDateTimeString())
            ->get()
            ->sortBy('created_at');

    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ';'
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            ['Date', 'Time', 'Value', 'Product']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function map($metric): array
    {
        $date = Carbon::parse($metric->created_at);
        return[
            $date->format('d.m.Y'),
            $date->format('H:i'),
            str_replace('.',',', $metric->value),
            $metric->silo->substance->substance_long
        ];
    }
```

This works nice for one "block". But how can I add a new block with one empty column next to the first one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a package like: https://github.com/maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel ?

Perhaps It does everything you want.

Comment: I already use laravel excel. My question refers to how I manage to get the desired result.
Maybe I should write the information again in the text. :)